# igraph shortest path export as vector

Tags: r, machine-learning, graph-theory, igraph

This is probably a very simple question but I cannot seem to solve it:

I'm using the *igraph* package and want to export the *vpath* part of the *get.shortest.paths* output as a vector so that I may work with it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, this is easy:
Simply use the *unlist()* command around the $vpath output.  For example:

unlist(get.shortest.paths(some.graph,from=some.node,to=some.other.node)$vpath)